# empties_to_bones

Tags: conversion, empty

With Blender 3.4, Windows 11  I have an imported model with some empties that could have been attachment points and I'd like to use them (for building object), I found this plugin but even after installing it it can't show up in the menus and im not sure if it works.

https://github.com/artellblender/empties_to_bones

Can anyone try and tell me if it works? It doesnt work for me

Comment: What do you mean, “attachment points”? It is very unclear as to what exactly you’re trying to achieve, so one can’t really say if the add-on works for your purpose or not.

Comment: I mean that from the import they could have been part of animation but now I'd like to make them bones as the addon suggests it does. Thats what im trying, once I have them as bones the rest I will deal with. But the menu doesnt show up and I tried 3 versions of Blender

Comment: Hi, imc7r, and welcome. This is not really a Blender question.. `empties_to_bones` is  a third-party add-on, published by Lucas Veber, who has published his contact details [here](http://www.lucky3d.fr/contact.php?page=contact) . He has responded relatively recently to  feedback. This question is off-topic, here, sorry. You would be better off contacting the author.

Comment: Thanks I will look to contact him

Answer (score 1):

The UI location and how to use the addon is detailed in the addon's repository already: [artellblender/empties_to_bones](https://github.com/artellblender/empties_to_bones)

After installing the addon, you should find its UI in the viewport's sidebar > Tool tab:

[image: addon ui]

> Download the .py file and install it in Blender. Select the empties and click Create Armature in the Tool tab.

Comment: I don not find the menus after I installed them but as the others suggested maybe will look the answer from the author of the script